# MongoDB, Mongoose: iterate over find results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB find() is a bit confusing to me. It can be used as a promise, with exec or callback. There are also next() and forEach() methods, but those seem to be available only in MongoDB shell, not in Mongoose (or can I create a cursor in Node.js/Mongoose?).

What I want to do is iterate over a collection, without loading all 1000+ found items into memory at once (instead one by one), and call some API for each found element and update the element in the DB.

Which is the most straightforward way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Streaming](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#streaming), via an [async iterator](https://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-async-iterators-in-node-js.html).

```
for await (const doc of Person.find()) {
  console.log(doc)
  doc.set('field', 'value')
  await doc.save()
}
```

For Node < 10.x

```
const cursor = Person.find().cursor()
for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {
  /** set and save **/
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This synthax required compilation to esnext, but this code worked for me: `Person.find().cursor(); for (let doc = await cursor.next(); doc != null; doc = await cursor.next()) {/**set and save**/ }`